# Invalid argument data passed into DataTable with ID "table"

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have my table1 on my dashboard so I wanted to create a button below to call out table2. However, it seems like there are some errors in my callback which I could not figure out. Was wondering if the error happens to be at  `pie = ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')[0]` . Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

This is my code

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import dash_table
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from engine import session
from model import datatable1,datatable2,datatable3
import plotly.express as px

table1 = pd.read_sql(session.query(datatable3).statement,session.bind)
table2 = pd.read_sql(session.query(datatable1.Name,datatable1.Number,datatable2.Address).join(datatable2).statement,session.bind)

app = dash.Dash(name, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP], suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
html.Div(children=[html.Div([
                html.H1("Heading", style={'text-align': 'center', 'fontSize': 30}),

                dash_table.DataTable(  
                    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i,
                              'deletable': False,  
                              'renamable': True  
                              } for i in table1.columns],
                    data=table1.to_dict('records'), 
                    page_current=0,
                    page_size=20,
                    page_action='native',
                    sort_action='native',
                    column_selectable="single",
                    sort_mode='multi',
                    style_table={'overflowX': '',
                                 'maxHeight': '1000px'},
                    style_header={'backgroundColor': 'rgb(119, 184, 199)'},
                    style_cell={'backgroundColor': 'rgb(207,227,232)',
                                'color': 'black',
                                'whiteSpace': 'normal',
                                'height': 'auto',
                                'textAlign': 'left',
                                },
                    export_format='xlsx', 
                    export_headers='display',
                    merge_duplicate_headers=True,
                    filter_action='native',  
                    editable=True,  
                    row_deletable=True,  
                    sort_by=[]),

                dbc.Row(
                    [
                        dbc.Col(children=[html.Div([(html.Button('Press',id='test1button')),
                        dash_table.DataTable(id='table')])])])
           ])])
  ])

@app.callback(Output('table', 'data'),
        Input('test1button', 'n_clicks'))

def clicked_output(test1button):
    ctx = dash.callback_context

    if (test1button == None):
        return ''
    else:
        pie = ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')[0]
        if pie == 'test1button':
            return [
                dash_table.DataTable(
                    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i,
                              'deletable': False,  
                              'renamable': True 
                              } for i in table2.columns],
                    data=table2.to_dict('records')
                )
            ]

if name == "main":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

My error message is

```
Invalid argument data passed into DataTable with ID "table". Expected an array. Was supplied type string. Value provided: ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to to with the context but you can achieve the desired result more simply with a callback of the kind:

```
    from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

    @app.callback(
        [Output("table", "data"),
         Output('table', 'columns')],
        Input('test1button', 'n_clicks')
    )
    def update_table(nclicks):
        """Retrieves data from the database

        Parameters
        ----------
        nclicks : int | None
            The number of times the button was pressed.
            Used to prevent initial update with empty state.

        Returns
        ------
        """
        if nclicks in [0, None]:
            raise PreventUpdate
        else:
            [data, columns] = get_data_and_columns()
            return [data, columns]
```

The error is due to the fact that the callback is activated by default and the first if statement evaluets to True. As such the function returns an empty string, hence error message. You can prevent the error by raising PreventUpdate.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, I tried using the code however `[data, columns] = get_data_and_columns()` give me the error of Unresolved reference 'get_data_and_columns'

Comment: you need to implement that part, I just provided the skeleton, you should know how to get your data and column names, Anyway you have already implemented it. Columns should be the list comprehension, and data should be ``table2.to_dict("records")``